# Upgrading has_magic_columns gem to support Rails 4/5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using this gem (https://github.com/latortuga/has_magic_columns) to allow my customers to define custom attributes on a per-account level. e.g. for the Orders object, customer A can add in "field1", "field2" as attributes, while customer B can add in "field3" and "field4", without me having to add them as actual columns to the orders table.

This gem stopped working past rails 3. I downloaded the gem code, and fixed a few minor issues with it, and upgraded the gemspec to support rails 4.2, but am stuck on the core issue, which is reflected in the spec failures such as this one:

UPDATED StackTrace:

```
1) HasMagicColumns on a single model allows setting and saving of magic attributes

 SystemStackError:
   stack level too deep
 # /Users/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/through_association.rb:6:in `through_reflection'
 # /Users/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/through_association.rb:68:in `stale_state'
 # /Users/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:76:in `stale_target?'
 # /Users/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:32:in `reader'
 # /Users/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:115:in `magic_attributes'
 # ./lib/has_magic_columns/active_record.rb:162:in `find_magic_attribute_by_column'
 # ./lib/has_magic_columns/active_record.rb:142:in `block in initialize_magic_columns'
 # /Users/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
 # /Users/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
 # ./lib/has_magic_columns/active_record.rb:141:in `initialize_magic_columns'
 # ./lib/has_magic_columns/active_record.rb:113:in `rescue in method_missing'
 # ./lib/has_magic_columns/active_record.rb:107:in `method_missing'
 # /Users/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:240:in `update_attribute'
 # ./lib/has_magic_columns/active_record.rb:154:in `block in initialize_magic_columns'
 # /Users/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
 # /Users/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
```

Comment: Looks like it's throwing an error in line 149 then it gets rescued and retried on line 110 over and over until it throws a stack level too deep error.  So try printing out the error on line 149 so you can see why it's blowing up.

Comment: I updated the description with a better stack trace

Comment: Not sure where you landed on this but if you started a new Gem to replace this I'd help you write it. We need this at my work and I think it's a fairly common enough problem for enterprise apps that it would get some traction and maintenance help.

Answer (score 2):

That gem is very old and unmaintained. As the readme says, it was originally written as a Rails 2 plugin and then packaged as a gem for use in Rails 3.

Unless you're planning a significant rewrite, I would not recommend to just "squash the test errors and get it to work".

Rather, why don't you use the new capabilities provided by Rails 4.2?

If you're using PostgreSQL, Rails 4 supports native column types like `hstore` and `JSON`:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_postgresql.html

If you're not on PostgreSQL, you can still use serialized attributes:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize

If you *really* need a facade interface that gives the illusion of real model attributes, you can either easily do it with [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) or you can reimplement the gem on top of what I've linked above.
I don't think that you need them though, because if your customers can define custom attributes, then I don't think that your code has them hardcoded anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. just to clarify your last point in your reply: The custom attributes are stored in MySQL, in the tables that are created by the has_magic_column's DB migration files. So the customer-specific mix-ins we have in our codebase do end up having to refer to those custom attributes by name

Comment: So you add new code based on what your customers have defined with a web GUI? e.g. A customer defines a new custom attribute `bar` on the model `Foo`, and after that you start writing code that does `Foo.first.bar`? That sounds very dangerous.

Comment: Not sure I see what danger you're referring to. We have a base platform, which is extensible per-customer-account. so the code that references their custom attributes only runs for their account / web-pages.  I should add that all the standard security checks for (sql injection, CSRF, XSS, etc.) also get run against these custom mix-ins.  We also run numerous audits/security pen-tests run against the codebase on a periodic basis to ensure there are no open security issue(s)

Comment: Also meant to add that these custom attributes are done by our support team on behalf of each account's setup. so there is full regression testing done on our QA environment before we setup the same custom attribute on Production (which also gets regression tested). I hope that clarifies your concern

Comment: Oh, right. I thought that they could change the ORM interface themselves with a sort of web UI. Makes sense then.

Comment: My recommendation to not rely on a gem that hasn't been updated in 6 years stands, though.